# Nohup at boot in Debian

Tags: debian, boot, nohup

I have a Debian server with kernel version 2.6.26-2-686. 

At boot time it reaches a line

```
`nohup: ignoring input and appending output to 'nohup.out'
```

and then it stops.

I can't get to the command prompt.

I can't use a remote terminal because the network is not working, so in order to fix it I'm trying to reach the command promt but I can't.

Is there a way to enter a selective boot or any other way to skip the nohup command and get to the prompt?

Comment: Boot a rescue system and work from there.

Comment: Also make sure to get the guy who set this up fired!